# os.chdir(src_path) error while accepting User Input using directory path in Python 3.9

Tags: python, windows, python-os

Code Snippet:

```py
src_path = input("enter the src direc : " )
print("src path ",src_path)
dst_path = input("enter the dest direc: " )

os.chdir(src_path) # It errors at this line
```

Getting this error after accepting the user input directory.

```py
enter the src direc : "C:\Src_html"  # (<< This is what i entered as the path, also tried giving "C\\ ' same error
src path  "C:\Src_html"
enter the dest direc: "C:\Src_html"
dest path  "C:\Src_html"
```

When the code gets here , it throws an error as shown below

```py
os.chdir(src_path)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"C:\\Src_html"'
```

Comment: Omit quotes in entered text; enter `C:\Src_html` instead of `"C:\Src_html"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the user input isn’t valid:

```py
enter the src direc : "C:\Src_html"
```

The user entered **"C:\Src_html"** instead of **C:\Src_html**. So that `src_path` save a path **with** a `"` at the start and the end, and as an `str` object (because input return `str`) it wraps the path again with another `'`. So that `src_path` looking like this:
**'"C:\Src_html"'**, Double `"`.

And you can see on the massage, that this is the path it is holding:

```py
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"C:\\Src_html"'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.. before posting I had tried giving without the "" ..It was not working , based on your explanation I realized user input was also having some whitespaces before and after. so used usr_input.strip() without the Quotes as you stated..it Worked 
Thank you ..usr_input = input("enter the Source directory path that has html files : " )
src_path = usr_input.strip()